# Getting Lex bot checksum value

Tags: amazon-web-services, chatbot, amazon-lex, aws-lex

I am trying to update a Lex bot using the python SDK put_bot function. I need to pass a checksum value of the function as specified [here](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/lex-models.html#LexModelBuildingService.Client.put_bot). How do I get this value?
So far I have tried using below functions and the checksum values returned from these

1. The get_bot with the prod alias
2. The get_bot_alias function
3. The get_bot_aliases function

Is the checksum value

Answer (score 0):

[Lex Model Building Service](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/lex-models.html#LexModelBuildingService.Client.put_bot):

> checksum (string) --
>   Identifies a specific revision of the $LATEST version.
>
> When you create a new bot, leave the checksum field blank. If you specify a checksum you get a BadRequestException exception.
>
> When you want to update a bot, set the checksum field to the checksum of the most recent revision of the $LATEST version. If you don't specify the checksum field, or if the checksum does not match the $LATEST version, you get a PreconditionFailedException exception.

You should first retrieve the `checksum` of your bot if you want to update it.

You should be able to use the same `checksum` that is returned from `get_bot_aliases()`.

This is the example response from `get_bot_aliases()` function.

```
{
    'BotAliases': [
        {
            'name': 'string',
            'description': 'string',
            'botVersion': 'string',
            'botName': 'string',
            'lastUpdatedDate': datetime(2015, 1, 1),
            'createdDate': datetime(2015, 1, 1),
            'checksum': 'string',                             --checksum here
            'conversationLogs': {
                'logSettings': [
                    {
                        'logType': 'AUDIO'|'TEXT',
                        'destination': 'CLOUDWATCH_LOGS'|'S3',
                        'kmsKeyArn': 'string',
                        'resourceArn': 'string',
                        'resourcePrefix': 'string'
                    },
                ],
                'iamRoleArn': 'string'
            }
        },
    ],
    'nextToken': 'string'
}
```

Comment: @AndyLon I noticed you may have tried to do this already. You should include the relevant code and/or errors associated with what you have tried, since this method should work.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to update intent, first do get_intent and save the checksum and use it in put_intent, If you are using the put_bot api, then first get_bot and save the checksum in that , use it in put_bot api